# Python library to parse .zip file

Tags: python, zip

I am looking for a way through which I can parse .zip file and identify  hex data and what fields they represent?
eg : In a .zip file local file header signature from initial 4 bytes, but how to identify the rest of hex and what they represent
I have goen through https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE_6.2.0.txt but could not track all the hex bytes

Comment: Why did you tag this question as a Python question? Do you have some Python code you are having a problem with?

Comment: I am trying parse it in python, if any libraries already are present would help my cause

Comment: Please include the Python code you have tried. Where does it not work? What exact error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `zipfile standard library`. Here [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will print the Hex Data for each file in the .Zip Archive

```
import os
import zipfile
import binascii

file = "test.zip"

with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as z:
    for filename in z.namelist():
        print('%s' % (filename) + "\n")
        if not os.path.isdir(filename):
            with z.open(filename) as f:
                hexdata = binascii.hexlify(f.read())
                print(hexdata); print("\n")
```